# Core Data One-To-Many Relationship Memory Usage

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-management, one-to-many

I am using core data where I have object A which has a one-to-many relationship with object B. In practice there could be 1000s of Bs related to one A.

My concern is that when I define the inverse of the one-to-many relationship, object A will have a NSSet containing 1000s of objects. I know these objects will be faulted until accessed, but there are still 1000s of some thin B wrapper object allocated.

I never want to access the B objects from A. I only advantage I can come up with is that it allows me to do a cascading delete of Bs when I delete A, which I do want.

Are there disadvantages of not defining the inverse relationship that I have missed? Also, maybe should I not be concerned about the memory usage of the 1000s of faulted objects for each object A?

**Update:**
It turns out that having the inverse relationship did end up causing me problems. Basically since I was using Core Data on the main thread, when my app launched, Core Data would basically lock the app up loading all these objects in to memory on the main thread.

The solution I came up with was to create a new version of object A which stores an id to object B instead of storing a reference to object B. This now eliminates the wasted memory of having all the faulted objects in the inverse relationship, thus eliminating the huge allocation of objects on first use.

Answer (score 0):

There are NUMEROUS disadvantages to not specifying an inverse.  You will have poorer performance, Core Data will need to work harder and you risk integrity issues.

Always, always, always have an inverse relationship.  Even if you will never use it, Core Data will.

You will not have a memory issue if you do not use it directly.  There is no reason to avoid having an inverse relationship.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I will leave the inverse relationship for now and run some tests with instruments to find out peak memory usage.

Comment: Not just for now.  If you remove the inverse relationship you will run into issues with Core Data.  The framework uses the inverse relationships as I have stated.  the relationship is not going to cause a memory issue.  If you end up with a memory issue it will be with something in your code, not the framework.

Comment: Use of an inverse relationship did end up causing me problems, see my update.